# data is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.GetADocument

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, forms, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error where when I click the button from one row of my table

```
data is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.GetADocument
```

What I wanted to do was when button is click it will take the row id from firestore and display the details of the row in my form.

This is the function that needs to be executed after button is clicked:

```
async function GetADocument(){
            var ref = doc(firestore, "ordered", data.id);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(ref)

            if(docSnap.exists()){
                boxEmail.value = docSnap.data().paidby;
                boxDate.value = docSnap.data().boughtAt;
                boxName.value = docSnap.data().cetegory;
                boxQty.value = docSnap.data().amount;
                boxAddress.value = docSnap.data().paidby;
                boxCode.value = docSnap.data().code;
                boxEstimation.value = docSnap.data().estimationDate;
                boxStatus.value = docSnap.data().status;
            }
            else{
                alert('No Document found')
            }
        }
```

This is the row of table that contains the button that will get the id from the firestore:

```
const q = query(collection(firestore, "ordered"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let id = doc.id;
                let data = doc.data();

                const list = document.getElementById("tbody1");
                const row = document.createElement("tr");

                row.innerHTML += `               
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.paidby)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">No. ${(data.numbur)}, Simpang ${(data.spg)}, Jalan ${(data.jln)}, ${(data.district)}, ${(data.code)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.product)} (${(data.amount)})</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">${(data.status)}</td>
                    <td class="grid-item">
                        <button type="button" id="viewDetail" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary my-2 ml-2" data-id="${id}">View Details</button>
                    </td>
                    `;

                    list.appendChild(row);

                    let detailView = document.getElementById('viewDetail');

                    detailView.addEventListener('click', GetADocument);
          });
          
        });
```

And, this is the form display:

```
<form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="emailBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User's Email</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" readonly class="form-control" id="emailBox" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="dateBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Bought At</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="dateBox" placeholder="Bought Date">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nameBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Item Bought</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="nameBox" placeholder="Item Bought">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="qtyBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quantity</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="qtyBox" placeholder="Quantity">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="addressBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="addressBox" placeholder="Address">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="codeBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address Code</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="codeBox" placeholder="Address Code">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="estimationBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estimation Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="estimationBox" placeholder="Estimation Date">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="statusBox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="statusBox" placeholder="Status">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Status to Delivered</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Record</button>
              </form>
```

And how I declare the inputbox in the JavaScript is like this:

```
        let boxEmail = document.getElementById('emailBox');
        let boxDate = document.getElementById('dateBox');
        let boxName = document.getElementById('namaeBox');
        let boxQty = document.getElementById('qtyBox');
        let boxAddress = document.getElementById('addressBox');
        let boxCode = document.getElementById('codeBox');
        let boxEstimation = document.getElementById('estimationBox');
        let boxStatus = document.getElementById('statusBox');
```

I think there is something wrong in my id declaration, which is in the second coding `data-id="${id}"` and also how I have reference the data-id. Can someone please help me?